# Including Azure Blob storage library causes problems in Spring

Tags: spring, jackson, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I have a spring application which, when I include the latest azure storage blob library:

```
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.14.0</version>
```

It changes my responses from Controllers to XML. I found this issue (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/7694) which seemed to fix my problem by excluding the XML data formatter like so:

```
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.14.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

My responses changed back to JSON, but when I try to use the library, I get a NoClassDefFoundError error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper$Builder
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:53)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:147)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.connectionString(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:286)
    at util.AzureUtil.blobClient(AzureUtil.java:47)
    at util.AzureUtil.getSecureReadParams(AzureUtil.java:24)
    at util.AzureUtil.getFullSecuredURL(AzureUtil.java:35)
    at RestServer.fabric.FilesFabric.getPresignedGetUrl(FilesFabric.java:37)
    at RestServer.controllers.api.FilesController.getSecureFileUrl(FilesController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 116 more
```

I could, theoretically, decorate all my Controllers' `@RequestMapping` with `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to tell the controllers to use JSON, but this seems like a hacky workaround. Is there any way to get the Azure Blob library to leave my responses alone, but still work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your xml configuration picks up instead of json.
You can try by changing this configuration like follows!

Create the following bean inside an existing `@Configuration` class

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer customConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        }
    };
}
```

or you can create a seperate `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    }
}
```